# Why did notepad++ suddenly display lines below cursor as white-on-gray?

Tags: notepad++, highlight

I fat-fingered something in Notepad++, instantly turning all lines below the cursor negative (gray bkgd, white chars). Saving or closing/opening did not change anything.

Finally figured out (in writing this) I must have hit the accent-grave.  It is at the end of line 1383 in the image.  Note that the ag is not visible in the image (it becomes visible if another line is selected.)  Every char following the ag displays "negative" - white-on-gray (see image). A second ag toggles the feature.

A google search for  (even if restricted to notepad-plus-plus.org) finds mostly instructions on how to enter letters with diacritical marks.

So: Is there a purpose to this feature?  What is it?

[image: negative lines]

Comment: i'm just guessing, but maybe to mark unimportant code that you don't need to focus on right now?

Answer (score 1):

Um, the answer is IN the question but here it is again: a "grave", or accent-grave, seems to toggle a sort of highlighting in Notepad++. The highlighting is done in a way that can make it difficult to see the grave.